# lp:launchpad-buildd download

Tags: launchpad

I received some emails about an error is occurred while build Ubuntu **LiveFS**, as email subscribe function.

I entered following command.

```
$ bzr branch lp:launchpad-buildd
```

I read it from https://launchpad.net/launchpad-buildd

And the command shows me following error message.

```
Permission denied (publickey).
ConnectionReset reading response for 'BzrDir.open_2.1', retrying
Permission denied (publickey).
bzr: ERROR: Connection closed: Unexpected end of message. Please check connectivity and permissions, and report a bug if problems persist.
```

So How to get and set the **publickey**? or Do I have a mistake with `bzr` command?

And what is **launchpad-buildd**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *publickey* is your public ssh key. The error is because it is trying to connect to the bzr server on Launchpad, using the *ssh* method. By default, it tries to connect using the same username as your local account, and will try to negotiate the session, using your existing *ssh* key. If you don't have an account on Launchpad, or someone else has an account with the same username you use on your PC, it will fail to connect. It should only do this if you have told bzr about your Launchpad username. If you are running a script from a cron job or other unauthenticated session, then it will not have the *ssh keyring* unlocked, and thus will not be able to use your *ssh identity* to authenticate with the server, though *bzr* is configured to do so.

If you want to run something in a cron job or unauthenticated session, which checks out a branch from Launchpad, you can create another user on your computer to use for such tasks, which does not have *bzr* configured to log in to Launchpad as your user. Instead, it will use the anonymous download over HTTP when checking out branches.